# Is it normal practice to take out the admin part from the monolith as a separate project and write the same models through the ORM?

Tags: architecture, sequelize.js, nestjs, microservices, typeorm

We have a monolithic JS + SequelizeORM project.

We decided to create a separate project for the admin panel.

Of course, it is assumed that in the monolith we did it faster, because. all functions are already implemented.

For new project, we chose NestJS + TypeORM. We are lucky that NestJS has already implemented ready-made libraries for working with the official admin panel provider.

Now we have to describe the same models through TypeORM as in Sequelize, and also disable "strong" synchronization with our database in the admin panel so that TypeORM does not change the primary keys and columns.

Is this approach correct?

A possible problem, it seems to me, is that if we change the table (columns, primary keys) in the monolith, then we will have to make changes to our TypeORM models. So it seems to me that we are doing something wrong.

Sorry for the stupid question, but this is our first experience.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution that can work without typeorm. You need to provide only db connection string i can recomend https://www.forestadmin.com/ . But this solution is not free and you cant self host it.